# Install libc++ on mac 10.6.8

Tags: clang, osx-snow-leopard, libc++, libclang

I'm currently trying to install the lib++.1.dylib on my mac. I followed the instructions here http://libcxx.llvm.org/ and downloaded the source. When I tried to `./buildit` I encountered a `clang++: command not found` error.

So I went here http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html and installed clang. Unfortunately now when I went back to installing libcxx, I still got the clang++ error. Clang itself works as `clang --help` brings up the help menu.

Installing Xcode isn't an option as I am runnning 10.6.8.

How do I proceed i.e. get the clang++ command to work?

Answer (score 1):

There is an instruction for build libc++ on 10.6 in github
https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/tree/apple

> To build on Mac OS X 10.6, you need a helper library and header found
>   here. cp cxxabi.h to /usr/include, and cp libc++abi.dylib to /usr/lib.
>
> Next:
>
> cd libcxx/lib
>
> export TRIPLE=-apple-
>
> ./buildit
>
> That should result in a libc++.1.dylib. To install it I like to use
>   links instead of copying, but either should work:
>
> cd /usr/lib
>
> sudo ln -sf path-to-libcxx/lib/libc++.1.dylib libc++.1.dylib
>
> sudo ln -sf libc++.1.dylib libc++.dylib
>
> cd /usr/include/c++
>
> sudo ln -sf path-to-libcxx/include v1

Link in instruction not work.
The libcppabi for 10.6 You can download on this link http://www.mediafire.com/download/2aq37hc97n4f47c/libcppabi.zip

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: I'd be wary of downloading from random sites like Mediafire where anyone can upload anything.

Comment: Per @RJHunter, the libcppabi from Apple's own Open Source repository for Mac OS X may be a better choice than MediaFire: http://www.opensource.apple.com/tarballs/libcppabi/libcppabi-14.tar.gz  Other versions can be found by traversing from the top-level of that site: http://www.opensource.apple.com/

Answer (score -1):

It is a fairly complex process to build libc++ on Mac 10.6, as it needs libc++abi to be present, which didn't ship with 10.6. So the working steps are as follow:

- Build Clang.
- Use this Clang to build libc++abi.

  - You have to make sure libc++abi and its header are properly placed so that in the next step in can be found.
- Then use this Clang to build libc++ and link to this libc++abi.

Also note if you are using Clang 3.3 instead of the latest development trunk, you will also need this patch (http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/Headers/unwind.h?r1=172666&r2=189535&view=patch) to unwind.h so that libc++abi can be built properly.

I have tested a working process and updated the homebrew-version formula so it works in homebrew out-of-the-box. You can check the details at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions/blob/master/llvm33.rb. Hope this helps.