# No type named 'function' in namespace std

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, clang, clang++

I wanted to pass lambdas around, so I defined a function like this:

```
double getInput(std::string inputDescription, std::function<bool(double)> isValid) { ... }
```

But gcc refused to compile it. I quickly learned I needed a compiler with C++11 support, so I downloaded clang 3.5 with MacPorts. I located clang++ and confirmed it was the right version (and I wasn't accidentally using the original clang 1.7):

```
$ /opt/local/bin/clang++ --version
clang version 3.5.0 (trunk 210448)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0
Thread model: posix
```

But even Clang 3.5 gives me:

```
tempConverter.cpp:14:52: error: no type named 'function' in namespace 'std'
double getInput(std::string inputDescription, std::function<bool(double)> isValid) {
                                              ~~~~~^
```

The full .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <functional>
#include <string>

static const double minTemp = -273.15;
static const double maxTemp = 500.0;

inline bool between(double x, double min, double max) {
    return min <= x && x <= max;
}

double getInput(std::string inputDescription, std::function<bool(double)> isValid) {
    double input;
    std::cout << inputDescription << std::endl;
    std::cin >> input;

    while (!isValid(input)) {
        std::cout << "Invalid input. Please reenter." << std::endl;
        std::cin >> input;
    }

    return input;
    /*double temp1, temp2;
    std::cout << "Please enter consecutively the upper and lower limits, both between " <<  MIN_TEMP << " and " << MAX_TEMP << "." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> temp1;
    std::cin >> temp2;
    while (!between(temp1, MAX_TEMP, MIN_TEMP) || !between(temp2, MAX_TEMP, MIN_TEMP)) {
        std::cout << "At least one of the temperatures is out of bounds. Please reenter:" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> temp1;
        std::cin >> temp2;
    }
    upper = std::max(temp1, temp2);
    lower = std::min(temp1, temp2);
    std::cout << "Please enter a positive stepsize, smaller than the difference between the limits." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> step;
    while (step < 0 || step > upper - lower) {
        std::cout << "The stepsize is out of bounds. Please reenter:" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> step;
    }*/
}

double toFahrenheit(double celsius) {
    return celsius*(9.0/5.0) + 32;
}

void printTable(double start, double end, double step) {
    std::cout << std::setw(10) << "Celsius" << "|" << std::setw(10) << "Fahrenheit" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std:setw(10) << "=======" << "|" << std::setw(10) << "==========" << std::endl;
    for (double i = start; i < end; i += step) {
        std::cout << std::setw(10) << i << "|" << std::setw(10) << toFahrenheit(i) << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    double start = getInput("Please enter the upper limit.", [](double x) { return between(x, minTemp, maxTemp); });
    double end = getInput("Please enter the lower limit.", [&](double x) { return x < start && between(x, minTemp, maxTemp); });
    double step = getInput("Please enter the stepsize.", [&](double x) { return x < end - start && x > 0; });
    printTable(start, end, step);
}
```

Is compiled with:

```
/opt/local/bin/clang++ -std=c++11 tempConverter.cpp -o tempConverter
```

Comment: Even though you've downloaded a newer compiler, it's certainly possible that you are still using an older c++ standard library.

Comment: Ah, that should be it. Is it possible to update your standard library?

Comment: This is way too broad because there are 9999 reasons why you could have an old library.

Comment: Can you include the full cpp file? Can you include the full command line arguments that you used? What version of OS X are you running? __Without this information, we can't reproduce your problem, which makes it very difficult to help you__.

Comment: 10.6.8. I'm sorry, don't behead me! :S @sharth

Comment: So, because you're on OS X, you have basically 2 choices. Upgrade to a newer version of os x, or follow the instructions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033255/install-libc-on-mac-10-6-8), to try and install a newer version of libc++ on your system.

Comment: Have you tried with `-stdlib=libc++`?

Comment: @Puppy, just one plausible reason: my OS came with an old library.

Comment: You are not supposed to place the answer in the question body. You can however accept one of the existing answers.

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to. I just hadn't seen you edited that flag into your answer (and undeleted it). I thought the only available answer didn't solve my problem and since my question is closed no other answers could be added (and I hate to search comment threads for solutions, so I thought I'd spare future visitors). I didn't expect you'd undelete your answer. @Jefffrey

Comment: @11684 Seems that what's left here, beyond your hickups and misconceptions, doesn't seem make up a really useful Q&A for future researchers. (I seriously decline to reopen, and propose to delete this, as soon possible)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Agreed, should I delete it?

Comment: @11684 _'should I delete it? '_ Yeah, I think that's the most appropriate action.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Can't. I upvotes Jefffrey's answer and my vote is locked...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You forgot to:

```
#include <functional>
```

or you forgot the C++11 flag:

```
-std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++
```

Comment: Actually, I didn't. I got both.

Comment: @11684: It would be fantastic to include things like this in your original question. Perhaps a full cpp file? and the arguments you used to compile it.

Comment: @11684 So apparently, you didn't have both.

Comment: @Jefffrey O:) (To be fair, my comment predates you editing the `-stdlib` flag in.)

Comment: @11684 [first revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25023881/1) says otherwise. :)

Comment: Gee, I thought I could read. Apparently, I need to revise on some elementary school material. (And in retrospect, my first comment seems not only ignorant but rude too. That wasn't intended.)

Comment: @11684 Apologies accepted. :)

Comment: inXcode yourProject/Targets/Build Settings/Apple Clang - Language - C++/ C++ Language Dialect . select "C++11 [-std=c++11]"

Answer (score 0):

You need a C++11 library and `#include <functional>` as well as a C++11 compiler.